# Jmeter - reset variables generated from Expression extractor

Tags: variables, jmeter, reset

I'm generating a number of variables in a script via the use of JSON and Regular expression extractors.

I need to reset these for each test record I process to ensure that each one uses the correct extracted value.

The problem (if it is a problem) is that the generated values consist of a number of array elements or groups.

example:

```
Regular expression extractor generating Reference Name: identifier
This generates:

 - Identifier
 - Identifier_g
 - Identifier_g0
 - Identifier_g1
```

I can successfully reset Identifier using `vars.put("Identifier",null);` at an appropriate point in a beanshell, however this doesn't reset the other items.

I have a number of these extractions taking place and the number of results they produce can vary, so the 'g' value above may change.

Any advice on how to reset these (or even if I need to)?

Comment: Are you using any of the `..._g` variables? Are you relying on them not present? if yes, what is the logic of your script?
General answer is: no, don't reset them, JMeter will do it for you on next match (see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor: "If no match occurs, then the refName variable is set to the default (unless this is absent). Also, the following variables are removed refName_g0, refName_g1, refName_g")

Comment: I am afraid accepted answer is just over engineering but why not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can reset one variable - you can reset them all, the only thing I would recommend is using [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) instead of Beanshell. The reasons are in:

- Groovy is more Java-compliant, you can use all modern Java features while with Beanshell you have to leave with [Java 5 language level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0)
- Groovy has a lot of nice [JDK enhancements](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/) providing some "syntax sugar" to base Java classes
- Groovy performance is much better as [well-behaved Groovy scripts can be compiled and cached](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/compile-groovyscript-at-runtime-allow-caching-of-compiled-source-to-avoid-recompilation-at-runtime-using-groovyclassloader/) while Beanshell are interpreted each time so Groovy scripts will perform much faster and have lesser memory footprint

References:

- [JMeter Best Practices: JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

And finally the relevant Groovy code to reset all the variables whose names start with `Identifier`

```
vars.getIterator().each {
    def name = it.getKey()
    if (name.startsWith('Identifier')) {
        vars.put(name, null)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but I'm getting a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet$1@... error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the extractor runs again it automatically cleans up old values.

this would only be a problem if you're using same var names in different extractors.

Comment: Agree, but i observed whenever i was using vars.get("myVarName") it was giving correct value as set by corresponding JSON extractor. But when i used ${myVarName} to get the value it was always giving the value set by very first thread. Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: That behavior can occur when you're using it within a script with caching enabled.  It will be evaluated at the time you *compile* the script, and then since that version of the script is cached, it will never change.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Regular expression` and you define Template as `$1$` for example it will take **only** `Identifier_g1` value, which means matching group 1 of Regular expression, the other values aren't used so in a normal flow you don't need to care them.

Groups Number are constant, basically the number of round brackets you create in `Regular expression` (\w+)=(\d+) will create 2 groups so you'll have to delete until Identifier_g2.

If you want you can add JSR 223 element to remove specific values.

You can choose between `JSR223 Sampler` or `JSR223 PreProcessor` or `JSR223 PostProcessor` depending on when you want it to be executed. Notice that Sampler will be included in reports and will marked as fail if script fails.

Code in your case:

```
vars.remove("Identifier");
vars.remove("Identifier_g");
vars.remove("Identifier_g0");
vars.remove("Identifier_g1");
```